# DataBricks Load multiples files from a Datalake Gen2 and union all

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I need some help with Databricks.
I have  100 files (in the same folder)  in Azure Data Lake Gen2 and I need to load and Union All  this files  Azure DataBrics.
I am able to load just one file.
I have tried to do this:

```
df = spark.read.csv(
"abfss://curated@http://azdlsdvdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/.../folder/*.csv")
```

and it didn't work.
And after that  I need to union all theses files

Can You guys help me with this issue?
Thank u

Comment: when you say it didn't work - what error do you get?

Comment: Helo @Alex Ott . IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: playSession2021-07-15T16:14:57.2085576Z.csv

Comment: Helo @Alex Ott . IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: playSession2021-07-15T16:14:57.2085576Z.csv . I removed the time (T16:14:57.2085576Z ) from the files and it worked well. To be honest  I dont know why it happens. Now I have all these files in the variable: df and I dont know how to manage this. I need to have only one file to be able to apply some analysis. Problably I will need to do a Union all, eliminate duplicate data but i didnt find how to do this.

Comment: do you have all these `....` in the path?

Comment: This is my path: df = spark.read.csv("abfss://curated@azdlsdvdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/area=CI/pj=folder/folder/folder/*.csv", 
                    header='true',inferSchema='true')

Comment: As I mentioned before after I renamed the files it worked well. Now I need to know how can I union all the variable df. How to set this in a Union all function?